# What does this obfuscated python code do?

Tags: python, obfuscation

And how does it work?

```
#########shift_jis:ascii:latin1:coding:rot13:euc_jp:utf_8:gb2312:unicode_escape
v=vag                                           (#(#(#( (#(#(#( (#(#(#( (#(#(#(
''.wbva                                         (#(       (#(   (#( (#( (#(
    znc(                              ynzoqn h:`(#(#(     (#(   (#( (#( (#(
     beq(                                       (#(       (#(   (#( (#( (#(
      h))/                                      (#(     (#(#(#( (#(#(#( (#(#(#(
117))`,(#(
   'h', h'h',""'h',  'h', h'h',  'h',  'h',""'h',  'h', h'h', h'h',  'h',""'h',
  h'h',  'h', h'h',""'h', h'h', h'h',  'h', h'h', h'h',  'h',  'h',  'h', h'h',
  h'h',  'h', h'h', h'h',  'h',  'h',""'h', h'h', h'h',  'h', h'h', h'h', h'h',
  h'h',""'h',  'h', h'h',""'h', h'h', h'h',  'h',""'h',  'h',  'h', h'h',""'h',
   'h',  'h',  'h',  'h',  'h', h'h',  'h', h'h',  'h', h'h', h'h', h'h',  'h',
  h'h', h'h',  'h', h'h', h'h', h'h', h'h',  'h', h'h', h'h', h'h',""'h',  'h',
  h'h',  'h',  'h', h'h', h'h',""'h', h'h', h'h',  'h',""'h',  'h', h'h', h'h',
   'h',  'h', h'h',  'h',  'h',  'h',  'h', h'h',  'h',  'h',""'h',  'h', h'h',
))),2);s="";rkrp('juvyr v:w=(v/v<<v/v<<v/v);s=pue(v&~-w**w)+s;v>>=8\acevag s,')
```

EDIT: Rot13's for your convenience.

```
i=int                                           (#(#(#( (#(#(#( (#(#(#( (#(#(#(
''.join                                         (#(       (#(   (#( (#( (#(
    map(                              lambda u:`(#(#(     (#(   (#( (#( (#(
     ord(                                       (#(       (#(   (#( (#( (#(
      u))/                                      (#(     (#(#(#( (#(#(#( (#(#(#(
117))`,(#(
   'u', u'u',""'u',  'u', u'u',  'u',  'u',""'u',  'u', u'u', u'u',  'u',""'u',
  u'u',  'u', u'u',""'u', u'u', u'u',  'u', u'u', u'u',  'u',  'u',  'u', u'u',
  u'u',  'u', u'u', u'u',  'u',  'u',""'u', u'u', u'u',  'u', u'u', u'u', u'u',
  u'u',""'u',  'u', u'u',""'u', u'u', u'u',  'u',""'u',  'u',  'u', u'u',""'u',
   'u',  'u',  'u',  'u',  'u', u'u',  'u', u'u',  'u', u'u', u'u', u'u',  'u',
  u'u', u'u',  'u', u'u', u'u', u'u', u'u',  'u', u'u', u'u', u'u',""'u',  'u',
  u'u',  'u',  'u', u'u', u'u',""'u', u'u', u'u',  'u',""'u',  'u', u'u', u'u',
   'u',  'u', u'u',  'u',  'u',  'u',  'u', u'u',  'u',  'u',""'u',  'u', u'u',
))),2);f="";exec('while i:j=(i/i<<i/i<<i/i);f=chr(i&~-j**j)+f;i>>=8\nprint f,')
```

Comment: Are you expecting somebody to run this for you and tell you the outcome?

Comment: Eventually prints "you have way, WAY too much time on your hands"

Answer (score 8):

You can run code like this at [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/). Running [it there](http://codepad.org/O7hqaAbE) leads to the output

```
Hello, World
```

The first line abuses python's [coding mechanism](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) to obfuscate the used characters. Then, it calculates a large number, and converts that number into a string, and prints that string.